# What does "up to" mean?

Tags: limits, terminology, morphism

There are several prior questions of the form "What does 'up to X' mean?"  The answers generally focus on "X", which has led some commentators to ask "What does 'up to' mean?" but in answer to that question, key to all the others, I've found no direct answers if not deafening silence.

One way of elaborating, so as to clarify, the question "What does 'up to' mean?" might be:

The phrase "up to" indicates motion along a dimension up to a point and not beyond.  So there is more at stake here than talking about the limiting point.

What exactly is this dimension?

Comment: I think you are drawing parallels where there are none. "unique up to isomorphism", or phrases similar, just mean that given any two objects satisfying the condition, there is an isomorphism between them. Since isomorphisms are viewed as an equivalence relation, this essentially is a form of uniqueness.

Comment: Perhaps so, and worse than a mistaken parallel is that by including in my question a potential parallel, I've now provided an escape route from answer the primary question.  I'll eliminate the parallel from the question so that the question doesn't end up in the same rut as the other questions.

Comment: You should ask on philosophy stackexchange. I can not even understand what you are asking. Do you have examples?

Answer (score 5):

"Up to" or "apart from" aren't precisely defined mathematical terms. They're "English padding" to quickly convey what we mean. For example, consider the fundamental theorem of arithmetic:

> "Every integer $n\geq 2$ can be written uniquely, up to reordering of the factors, as a product of primes.

or a slightly different phrasing:

> "Every integer $n\geq 2$ can be written uniquely, apart from the order of the factors, as a product of primes.

or yet another phrasing:

> "Every integer $n\geq 2$ can be written uniquely, modulo the order of factors, as a product of primes.

One typically does not wish to write out the more formal and cumbersome statement which avoids the phrase "up to" or "apart from"

> For every integer $n\geq 2$, there exists $k\in\Bbb{N}$, and prime numbers $p_1,\dots, p_k$ such that $n=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i$. Furthermore if $m\in\Bbb{N}$ and $q_1,\dots, q_m$ are primes such that $n=\prod_{j=1}^mq_j$, then $m=k$ and there is a bijection $\sigma:\{1,\dots, k\}\to\{1,\dots, k\}$ such that for every $i\in \{1,\dots, k\}$, we have $p_i=q_{\sigma(i)}$.

In this formulation, we have completely avoided any "informal" language (ok one bit of informality left in the statement is my use of $\dots$, but I think we can side-step this minor detail), and used only "$\forall$ and $\exists$ and $\implies$ and $=$".

So, "up to" in this case is not referring to an "upward motion" along some axis/set or anything like that. So this has little to do with any dort of convergence/limits of any kind.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere!    "regardless of", "ignoring", "independent of", "unconstrained by"... and so forth seem to work as well for your particular example.  More commonly people run across the more technical terms such as "isomorphism" (which is pretty easy to find clear definitions easily understood by even a middle school math class).  So now it is pretty easy to see why people keep asking the same question!  Websters does define the phrase "up to" in the vernacular and it has nothing to do with its math usage.

Answer (score 0):

One extremely vague and informal way to think about it is that equality is the strictest sense in which two objects can be the same. So, we are "going the furthest" in terms of how much we require the two things to be similar, in that they are exactly identical. By saying "up to", we mean that we aren't going *that* far, and some weaker notion of sameness is enough.

For example, "there is one group of order 3 up to isomorphism" means, okay, there may be many groups of order 3 which aren't equal (e.g. group of rotational symmetries of a triangle, and group of integers mod 3), but they're the same if we "stop at" isomorphism and don't be so strict as to require equality. This is how I always thought of the term "up to", anyway.

Comment: Thanks for a your perspective differing, as it apparently does, from the one @peak-a-boo  set forth.  I say "differing" because his substitution _apparently_ doesn't hold with yours -- at least in the example you used.  Could you provide a textual substitution as he did so they may be compared straight across?

Comment: @JamesBowery I don't really see why you need a substitution. The phrase "up to" is used precisely because it is the most appropriate in this context, I find it hard to find a replacement that would work for all contexts. peek-a-boo's suggestions are for the sake of illustration only, and I don't think they are suggesting that "apart from" or anything else is a textual substitution for "up to" which always works. They only rephrased it to explain the meaning of "up to" in context.

Comment: @JamesBowery In any case, for my example we could say something like "there is only one group of order three, if we consider isomorphic groups to be the same". You could even say something like "there is only one group of order three, disregarding isomorphic groups". But the first is a bit lengthy and the second is awkward phrasing IMO. Anyhow, I don't think I disagree with peek-a-boo's perspective, this is just another way to look at the same thing. Such soft questions never have precise answers anyway.

Comment: @JamesBowery I don't think YiFan's answer's perspective differs from mine. It's just phrased differently. Again, you seem to be hung up on the "English padding", i.e the extra fluff words we add to write out an idea as a complete grammatically correct sentence. For the example given here "there is one group of order 3, up to isomorphism", if one doesn't like such "imprecise" (it's really not) or unexplicit sentences, one can say the following explicit statement: "For any two groups $G$ and $H$, if $|G|=|H|=3$ then $G$ is isomorphic to $H$".

Comment: Or if you want to be SUPER precise about saying "only one group", one can do the following. Let $\Gamma_3$ be the set of all groups of order $3$, and define a relation $\sim$ on $\Gamma_3$ by saying that for any $G,H\in \Gamma_3$, we define $G\sim H$ if and only if there is an isomorphism $f:G\to H$. Then, $\sim$ is clearly an equivalence relation on $\Gamma_3$. The claim is then that the quotient set $\Gamma_3/\sim$ contains only one element (i.e there is only one equivalence class).